# R multiple urls into lapply

Tags: r, function, lapply

I have a list of urls in a character vector and I want to pause the process between
queries because if not the x queries is rejected.

```
urls=c('url1','url2','url3')
```

here is want I want to do

```
htmlpages=lapply(urls,function(x) readLines(x) Sys.sleep(0.3))
```

Comment: use `{`... `htmlpages=lapply(urls,function(x) {y <- readLines(x) ; Sys.sleep(0.3), y})`.  But much better to write this out in a multiline function for clarity.

Comment: thanks for your help,if i understand the process;it stores the data in y temporally,then pause ,then return y into the list,then process the next url?can you explain the syntax semicolon then comma?

Comment: The comma was an error and should be a semicolon.  See what Richie wrote though.  The single line is a dangerous plan.

Answer (score 10):

As Justin suggested, formatting is the key.

```
htmlpages = lapply(
  urls,
  function(x) 
  {
    y <- readLines(x)
    Sys.sleep(0.3)
    y
  }
)
```

---

Update: functionality for waiting between calls is now built into purrr.

```
library(purrr)
slow_readLines <- slowly(readLines, rate = rate_delay(0.3))
lapply(urls, slow_readLines)
```

or for a full purrr solution

```
library(purrr)
slow_readLines <- slowly(readLines, rate = rate_delay(0.3))
urls %>% map(slow_readLines)
```

Comment: You can separate multiple commands using a semicolon, `;`, but in general it is better to write your code for clarity.  Badly formatted code is a breeding ground for bugs.