# Apply list of functions across columns in R to fill in table

Tags: r, function, apply

I have a dataframe in R, let's call it `df`, which I would like to analyse in terms of mean, median, standard deviation, IQR etc column-wise. I have prepared succinct functions (where it's not just `mean` or `sd`) which can take a vector as input and output, say, the IQR or coefficient of variance. Now, if I want to apply any of these across the attributes (columns), I could use `IQRs <- apply(df,2,IQR)` for example.

My question is, how can I apply *multiple* of these functions together (really, I want to chain them all together), so as to fill in a table where there will be one column for the attributes and then one column per function (i.e. Means will be one column, IQRs will be one column), and the different attributes of the data-frame (which were columns in `df`) will be rows of this table (listed in the first column)?

Comment: Unfortunately can't vote to close as dupe(immediately downvoted lol). Anyway, there exists a question on `aggregate` for instance. You can also do it in `*apply` with `{}` or the fancy `mutate` from `dplyr`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473952/r-multiple-functions-into-lapply) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your data looked like this:

```
set.seed(69)
df <- data.frame(A = rnorm(5), B = rnorm(5), C = rnorm(5))
```

And your function names were like this:

```
funcs <- c("mean", "median", "sd", "var", "min", "max")
```

Then you can use an `apply` inside an `lapply` like this:

```
as.data.frame(setNames(lapply(funcs, function(f) apply(df, 2, as.name(f))), funcs))
#>        mean     median        sd       var       min       max
#> A -0.3546864 -0.3348139 0.5948611 0.3538597 -0.949889 0.3743156
#> B -0.2016318 -0.9039467 1.4092795 1.9860687 -1.571073 1.4440935
#> C -0.3537707 -0.1691765 0.7955558 0.6329090 -1.311374 0.4149940
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tidyr::gather` and `dplyr::summarize`:

```r
# Toy data
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 11:20)

# Libs
library(tidyverse)

# Code
df %>% 
    gather(var, val) %>% 
    group_by(var) %>% 
    summarize(med = median(val), mean = mean(val), iqr = IQR(val))
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  var     med  mean   iqr
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 x       5.5   5.5   4.5
2 y      15.5  15.5   4.5
```